# Django - Error when changing from GET to POST

Tags: python, django, post, axios, get

I have a react/django application that works fine when the request is a GET request. For example, in the React part I have the following

```
sendRequestParameters(url) {
        axios({
            url: url,
            method: 'get',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRFToken': 'csrf_token',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            },
            params:{
                'TECHNOLOGY': JSON.stringify(this.state.technologySelectedValue),
                // more parameters here, all in the same format
            },
            paramsSerializer: function(params) {
                return qs.stringify(params, {arrayFormat: 'repeat'})
            }
        }).then((response ) => {  
           console.log(response.data);
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        }) 
    }
```

Then, in the backend, I get the parameters and return them (this function is called in another function where the returned parameters are used, that's why there is a return statement).

```
def extractParameters(request):
    TECHNOLOGY = json.loads(request.GET.get('TECHNOLOGY'))
    # more parameters extracted here, same format

    return TECHNOLOGY etc.
```

That all works fine. However, I need to change to POST requests, and when I make two small modifications to do this, I get an error. In the front end request with axios, I change the `method: 'get'` to `method: 'post'`. Then, in the backend, I change `TECHNOLOGY = json.loads(request.GET.get('TECHNOLOGY'))` to `TECHNOLOGY = json.loads(request.POST.get('TECHNOLOGY'))`

This gives me the following error in the terminal

```
TECHNOLOGY = json.loads(request.POST.get('TECHNOLOGY'))
raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType
```

All I'm doing is a simple change from GET to POST and it's causing this error. I've been reading through the Django documentation but am stuck. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using DRF (Django REST Framework). You can get it using [`data`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#request-parsing):

```py
TECHNOLOGY = request.data.get('TECHNOLOGY')
```

> Also sorry, but UPPERCASE request params and variables are used never.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried that and many other things but it's not working. There's some deeper issue going on - it's for a project on a timeline that I just finished and I had to leave them at GET, no big deal.